# How to use the count result over an specific date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this, I'm using SSMS to build a query from multiple tables:

```
2016-09-20  Mike  8
2016-09-20  Dave  8
2016-09-20  John  8
2016-09-20  Mike  8
2016-09-21  John  8
2016-09-22  Dave  8
```

I need this result (Need to count how many times in the same date the name repeats and divide the 3rd column value between the result):

```
2016-09-20  Mike  4 -- bold
2016-09-20  Dave  8
2016-09-20  John  8
2016-09-20  Mike  4 -- bold
2016-09-21  John  8
2016-09-22  Dave  8
```

Comment: Have you attempted anything or are you looking for someone to do this for you?

Comment: looks like you will end up with duplicates. Why don't you group by Date and Name.

Comment: I'm trying to solve it, but now I am in a brain break , -I will use Kamil answer, thanks.

Duplicates is not my issue, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
select 
  date_column, 
  name_column, 
  int_column/count(*) over (partition by date_column, name_column) AS int_result
from yourtable
```

Introducing window function `count(*)` which counts rows with the same `date_column, name_column` and divides the `int_column` by the result.

Result:

```
 date_column | name_column | int_result
-------------+-------------+-----------
 2016-09-20  | Dave        |         8
 2016-09-20  | John        |         8
 2016-09-20  | Mike        |         4
 2016-09-20  | Mike        |         4
 2016-09-21  | John        |         8
 2016-09-22  | Dave        |         8
```

Comment: Check it out on your data and if it suits your needs please feel free to accept this answer. [Click here to see how it's done.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: I have tried but the SSMS query auto correct just let me write this:

Comment: int_column / COUNT(*)

Comment: Never mind, I got it work from sql code view, thanks it was a great solution